# str.replace com IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python

Tenho o seguinte código que retorna

```
ref_arquivo = open("Castalia-tratado.txt","r")

for linha in ref_arquivo:
    valor = linha.split(" ")
    valor[2] = valor[2].replace('\n','')
    print (valor)
```

se comentar a linha `valor[2]=valor[2],replace('\n','')` o `print` imprime:

```
['0', 'END', 'signal\n']
['0', 'Received', 'packet\n']
['1', 'SET', 'STATE\n']
['1', 'completing', 'transition\n']
['0', 'RX', '>>\n']
['0', 'TRATAR', 'DADOS\n']
['0', 'XXXXXXXXXXXX', 'SINK\n']
['0', 'SINK', 'Received\n']
```

Com a linha descomentada dá o seguinte erro:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "le.py", line 16, in <module>
valor[2] = valor[2].replace('\n','')
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Estou tentando fazer um `if` para verificar se o campo `valo[1]` é igual a um determinado texto `AND` `valor[2]` é igual a outro texto, desta forma:

```
if ( valor[1] == "RECEBIDO" ) and ( valor[2] == "BEACON" ):
            recebido1 = recebido1 +1
elif ( valor[1] == "SENDING" ) and ( valor[2] == "BEACON" ):
            send1 = send1 + 1
```

Que também dá o mesmo erro de index.

Comment: Seu código funcionou como o esperado, sem dar o erro que diz ter dado: https://repl.it/@acwoss/sopt-question-382655. Por favor, edite sua pergunta e elabore um [mcve] demonstrando o problema. Certifique-se também que está analisando o código certo e nas linhas certas.

Comment: O erro que reportei é apenas a parte que o terminal retorna. O código em si é muito maior e de qualquer forma, não está funcionando. o arquivo de dados possui mais de 100.000 linhas e eu preciso das informações 266150.195401607991SN.node[1].Communication.Radio           Sending Packet, Transmission will last 0.004128 secs (está é a linha 345.681) entre colchetes (no caso é o número do nó) e as ocorrências, neste caso Sending Packete (só estas duas strings)

Comment: O que eu quero fazer é verificar quantas vezes para 0 o RECEBIDO BEACON e o SENDING BEACON ocorreram em algumas milhares de linha.

Comment: Então parece que o erro está em outro lugar, que você não colocou na pergunta e, assim, não há como ajudar. Talvez é alguma linha do seu arquivo de mais de 100.000 linhas que não possui três valores. Cabe a você verificar se é o arquivo que está errado ou se realmente a linha pode não ter 3 valores. Só conseguiremos ajudar a partir do momento que você elaborar o [mcve] que realmente demonstre a sua situação.

Comment: Olá Anderson, obrigado por sua ajuda. Coloquei em https://repl.it/@acwoss/sopt-question-382655 meu atual código, após diversas alterações e um exemplo do log real, pois aquele que passei foi após trata-lo (para evitar erros como o que você mencionou, preferi usar o original).Consegui até rodar o programa, pois era um valor passado errado por mim no index dentro do segundo if que causava o erro, porém de qualquer forma não está fazendo o que deveria fazer. Poderia me auxiliar?

Comment: Consegui resolver. Obrigado pela ajuda.

Answer (score 0):

Pode usar o `linha.strip("\n")` para remover a quebra de linha. Se precisar do `split` a sintaxe é `linha.split()` para remover o espaço.

```
for linha in ref_arquivo:
    valor = linha.strip("\n") # remove a quebra de linha         
    print (valor)
```